# Flask: Use File in multiple routes

Tags: python, pandas, flask, routes

I have an Programm based on Flask. It will be running only Windows.
I created an upload route

```
import os
from flask import Flask,redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       file = request.files['file']
       return redirect(url_for('overview'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Later the Program will have an overview with some buttons with links to other routes.

I would like to use the file from the upload within the other routes. 
Is this possible without saving the file (its all local)?

I thought about to use the location path and save it to a session.
But I don't know if this is possible or a really nice Idea.

Comment: you can save the path in a variable and pass it in when ever you need it.

Comment: or create an object of the file and then use the object when you need it

Comment: how can I get the path from request.files? When I print the file it says: <FileStorage: 'Ergebnisse.xls' ('application/vnd.ms-excel')>